# Javascript suddenly stop working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

[image]I have asp.net project with Javascript code, i worked with Internet explorer 8, after i did finish the project i tried to run this project on All other browser (Chrom, Firefox, Opera, Safari) and suddenly each of these browser are not run javascript.

I was supprised that after 1 minutes i went back to the Internet Explorer and is also not running javascript.

I don't know what the problem, I've tried to comment partial of my javascript and it is not work, and comment all the left javascript and it's still doesn't work.

I have very long JavaScript code vith collaboration with AJAX, i have tried to remove paragraph by paragraph and it still doesnt work, i have tried to remove All the java script and run only "Hello word" simple java script code that fire from click event and it does not work. Although with other pages it work fine (alse the same "Hello word" simple code, the problem causes suddenlt til this moment every thing work fine. I attached sample code from the javascript code, it doesent metter because my there is a lot of java script code.  Thank you every one that response i willi appreciation  your response ! By the way there is none error, except when i click the button the java script write "

Comment: It's going to be very difficult for anyone to help you with this without any code. Remember, we've never seen it, and can't see your monitor from here. The only information we have to go on is what's in your question, and you've provided none.

Comment: there could be a javascript error. Open it up in firefox and get firebug and see if there are any errors

Comment: Is there any bug detected by , say, firebug? Check the JavaScript is turned on? Save the page as HTML, and remove codes until it works to narrow down the problem? Set break point at the beginning of JavaScript to debug?

Comment: I can't see any bugs, because I can't see any code.

Comment: My guess is that your using some IE proprietary stuff and in the other browsers it is causing some error to be throw, unlike IE in the case some thing is throw(and are not caught) the javascript execution simply stops(in most browsers) and no message box is show to alert us, try to press crtl+shift+i in chrome and reload the page guess e error would be logged to the console.

Comment: I have very long JavaScript code vith collaboration with AJAX,

Comment: I update my Question with response to all of you.

Comment: You have a CODE tag for code, don't post screenshots of code :( And maybe you should take a look at your JS Console in some browser that has one. My guess is that you code is not loaded at the document ready.

Comment: All my browser have javascript enabled, Other pages are run javascript fine, i am not sure but the problem can be from the UTF-8 of UTF-16 thea i eddited before this problem were bagin?

Answer (score 0):

Better use some some browser plugins/integrations for checking javascript error. Try firebug in firefox or developer tools in IE. If you are doubtful of the path taken by your web application, try Fiddler to check your site.

If there is a referencing problem in case of master page usage or url routing usage or other then you can reference the javascripts and css in the following manner:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/style.css") %>' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js") %>"></script>
```